Unable to Import Locally Hosted Flutter Package Despite Successful Installation
I'm working on a Flutter application that utilizes a third-party map solution. This third-party provider doesn't offer a Git link or a pub.dev hosted package; instead, they provided the SDK files directly. I decided to manage this dependency by hosting the package locally and specifying its host in the pubspec.yaml file.
  custom_sdk:
    hosted:
      name: custom_sdk
      url: http://localhost:8080
    version: 4.16.5

After running flutter pub get I see the package being installed, I am unable to import it in my Dart files using:
import 'package:custom_sdk/any_file.dart';

Note: in this path /.pub-cache/hosted I see two entries, one for pub.dev and one for my localhost, this maybe the reason? If so, any ideas on how to fix it?

I managed to resolve the problem. My package server was working correctly, but there was one small detail causing an issue with the .tar.gz archive process. The generated archive included an additional library directory inside the XXX-version.tar.gz file.
Initially, the output structure was:
XXX-version/my-packaged/files

However, the correct structure should be:
XXX-version/files

I hope this helps someone save a few hours of debugging in the future!
